# NSString to String or Char[]

Tags: c#, objective-c, string, unity-game-engine, nsstring

I am working on a unity project in C# where I have to call a method in objective C. My problem is that I don't know a way to receive an NSString from my objective C plugin and use it in Unity as a string. I have been searching for an answer but every answer that I can find involves turning the NSString into a char* but Unity does not allow me to receive a char* using:

[DllImport("__Internal")]

private static extern char* IOSGetLastConnectedDevice();

I would appreciate the help...

Comment: Please provide your code-attempts, it will help the community to grasp some context. Also, you can greatly improve the quality of your post by link to documentations, language, software version and so on. The more you give, the more you get :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `char    *strdup(const char *__s1);`, and pay attention to the encoding of `__s1`